# Connecting to an Access database that has a database password

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I've password protected an mdb file but then I cannot access it on vb.net. I don't know the correct code for defining the password.
this is my current code, I know its wrong, but I don't also know the correct code:

```
conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=F:\search.mdb;pwd=nit"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccess2007file.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=MyDbPassword;"
```

is the correct format for your connection string.

Check out http://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2007 for more info.

Comment: While the password parameter is correct, you have the wrong provider.  Just a FYI so the questioner doesn't just copy and paste it.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the connection string should look like this:

```
conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\mydatabase.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=MyDbPassword;"
```

Here is a link to a site which can help with connection string questions [ConnectionStrings.Com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access)  HTH