# How to connect to an Access database protected with a password

Tags: vb.net

I tried to connect my application to a database that is protected with a password, but I find it difficult to do so ..  I have used this code without using a password and run without problems...

```
    Dim Con As OleDb.OleDbConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim DBProvider As String
    Dim DBSource As String
    Dim DS As New DataSet
    Dim DA As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim Sqlstr As String

    Try
        DBProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
        DBSource = "Data Source =" & App_Path & "/DBase/Dbx.accdb;"
        Con.ConnectionString = DBProvider & DBSource
        Con.Open()
        Sqlstr = "SELECT * FROM Dat_Barang"
        DA = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(Sqlstr, Con)
        DA.Fill(DS, "Query")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Con.Close()
    End Try
```

then I tried to secure my database using a password and I add the code that I found on the internet and the results are not much different from that without a password .. this code ..

```
DBSource = "Data Source =" & App_Path & "/DBase/Dbx.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=1234567890;"
```

But when I run the application, my application becomes error ..

> ERROR MESSAGE :
>
> "Cannot open database ", it may not be a database that your
>   application recognizes, or the file may be corrupt."

my question is how to fix this..?? thanks.

Edit :

I use Office 2013..

Comment: Looks like duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049017/connecting-to-an-access-database-that-has-a-database-password

Comment: Yes..The question may be the same but the results are not the same..

Answer (score 0):

Inside `Access`, run the repair utility. It is located in

```
Tools > Database Utilities > Compact and repair database
```

Comment: @CrazyThink Try this provider: `Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;`

Comment: New Error Message : Unrecognized database format.. i think that provider for office 2000-2003.. thanks.

Comment: @CrazyThink OK, as long as you know you're using the correct provider, I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Access for years now, but this is the library code I used to use.  Have a look through it.  The last time I updated it was for the .accdb file format.

```
Public Overloads Sub Connect(pDatabase As String, pPassword As String)

    '[set up some paths and check the file exists stuff...]

    Dim vConnection = String.Empty
    If pDatabase.EndsWith(".accdb") Then
        vConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
    Else
        vConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
    End If
    vConnection &= "Data Source=" & pDatabase & ";"
    vConnection &= "Password='';"               ' Leave blank!
    vConnection &= "User ID=Admin;"             ' You may need to modify this!
    vConnection &= "Mode=16;"                   ' Standard sharing - for network access = adModeShareDenyNone
    vConnection &= "Jet OLEDB:Database Password='" & pPassword & "' ;"  ' Password goes here, not above.
    vConnection &= "Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;"
    vConnection &= "Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;"         ' Don' t lock 
    vConnection &= "Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops= 2;"
    vConnection &= "Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;"
    vConnection &= "Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;"        ' Do NOT create a system database (.mdw)
    vConnection &= "Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;"
    vConnection &= "Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;"
    vConnection &= "Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;"
    vConnection &= "Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;"

    ' [do stuff with connections, etc.
End Sub
```

I hope it's useful for someone - god knows I'll probably never look at it again!