# Open password protected Microsoft access file through vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to open access databse mdb file with below code.

```
Public connection As OleDbConnection 
connection = New OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & database & "';Jet OLEDB:Database Password =12345")

connection.Open()
```

But it gives error that "Not a valid password"
Please help!

Comment: I tried this as well,connection = New OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & database & ";Persist Security Info=False;Jet OLEDB:Database Password =12345;")


        connection.Open()

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049017/connecting-to-an-access-database-that-has-a-database-password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [working example](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=A3D5A9A9A28080D1!261&authkey=!APXxDJGWUdafTrQ&ithint=file%2Czip) to try out, note the password is in a connection string created with a connection string builder.