# Connection string with a network password

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, connection-string

I have a problem when centralizing a database. (I will not use MySQL etc.. since this is only a small application. I will use access only.)

Problem: Code won't run because there is a password on a network.

Based on [www.connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/) this is my connection string:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\server\share\folder\myAccessFile.accdb;
```

This code can access the database on a network, but only after I manually access the file and input the password.

Is there a way to input a network password using code in VB.NET?

Note:

I tried this search on this website: "access database on a network with a password in VB.NET" but no luck or my query is incorrect

Comment: Quick look on the connection string site shows this; `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\server\share\folder\myAccessFile.accdb;
Jet OLEDB:Database Password=MyDbPassword;` Is this what you are after?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049017/connecting-to-an-access-database-that-has-a-database-password ?

Comment: "There is a password on the network" is pretty vague.  What *exactly* is the situation here?  What is your OS?  Is this Active Diretory; are we talking about file share permissions or ACLs?

Comment: If the password is needed for the file share and not the database, you may need to P/Invoke [`WNetAddConnection2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385413(v=vs.85).aspx) before accessing the database.  You can use [`WNetCancelConnection2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385427(v=vs.85).aspx) to clean up after.  Not sure if there is an easier way to "NET USE" in .NET - e.g. perhaps WMI?

Comment: At Bugs and muffi: What I mean is network password not database password, sorry if my question is confusing for you. @Mark I'll check the links now. Thanks for the reply :-)